# Crystal Reports - Is TCrpe for Delphi threadsafe?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, crystal-reports

**Short**: Is it ok to execute the TCrpe component from within a non-VCL main thread?

**Long**: I use the TCrpe component to create reports for Crystal Reports.
Until now I used the component within the VCL main thread and everything was fine.

But now I moved the component into a background thread. There is only 1 instance of the component at a time, and it is only accessed by one single thread, which is not the VCL main thread.

On my test environment everything seems to be fine. 
But on the production environment the application crashes from time to time: Access violations; Invalid Pointer operations; List index out of bound exceptions. The exceptions can occur almost anywhere, and not always I get an exception stacktrace.

So: Is it ok to execute the TCrpe component from within a non-VCL main thread?

I looked at the source code, and some GUI related things are used there, which make me doubt. They even call

```
while not PrintEnded do Application.HandleMessage;
```

from there. Actually this code path is not activated due to my report settings; however, it makes me wonder whether the TCrpe component is inteded for usage in background threads at all.

Also, for some reports the TCrpe component shows an own form for the user to enter additional report parameters. Is this an indicator that they are messing up the main message event loop? Or could it be that they are using an own message queue for that form?

Comment: `while not PrintEnded do Application.HandleMessage` will be in a printer callback and is what keeps your UI responsive whilst printing.

Comment: @David Yes, but it would be deadly to call it from within a thread which is not the VCL main thread, wouldn't it?

Comment: not necessarily. If you call it on a thread that has not created any windows then there might not even be a message queue and it will be harmless.

Answer (score 2):

If this component shows any forms then it is using VCL components.  All use of the VCL in an application must be done in the same thread, it's a requirement of the VCL.

You need to find a design that runs all the VCL code in the main application thread.

Having said all that, this doesn't explain why you see crashes only away from the test environment. The advice about threading is valid, but you most probably have a different problem.

Comment: Well, I am actually not sure whether the component shows the form (for entering report parameters) or whether a loaded dll shows the form.

Comment: @nang If running CR out of a worker thread was a problem then I believe it would cause you problems on your test environment. The advice I stated stands, you need to obey the VCL threading rules, but I suspect your problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: Regarding the difference between the test environment vs. production environment: I agree. However, it could be that I am simply not able to reproduce the interaction patterns of real life users. Further, the production environment is a Citrix/Windows2000 server, and test environment is Vista.

Comment: @nang In order to rule out VCL threading problems you are going to have to find out if you create any VCL components with window handles, e.g. TWinControl descendants.

Comment: @david I would definitly prefer it if I knew that the bug was not in my threading code. But what else could be a reason? The old, single threaded version of the Application worked fine. Then I intruduced the background thread and the problems started. So my bet is: The component is not thread safe, or I have a bug in my threading code.

Comment: @david "..window handles.." Ok, I'll do that. Thanks!

Comment: @nang Moving working single-theaded code into a background thread doesn't generally introduce bugs (with the proviso that you aren't calling VCL code). Where the bugs appear typically is when you synchronise. You haven't actually multi-threaded any code, you've just moved it into a background worker.